# How to render correctly first column in GridView component?

Tags: wicket

I am displaying a **meal week calendar** using a GridView component. I added to the first column (with `newRowItem()` method) a label with name: 'Breakfast', 'Lunch', 'Supper', 'Dinner' etc...

When I click first time in a `Select` link  (to show calendar) component renders correctly. When I click `Close` link and then `Select` link again I get: 'Label cannot be cast to MarkupContainer' error

**Edit**: *without first column the 'meal week calendar' component works as expected (no errors)*

```java
Last cause: class org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label cannot be cast to class org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer (org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label and org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @24fab44a)
WicketMessage: Error attaching this container for rendering: [Form [Component id = form]]
```

[image]

[image]

Below my code:

```java
public class SimpleMealCalendarFormPopup extends Panel
{
    public SimpleMealCalendarFormPopup(String id, IModel<Meal> mealModel)
    {
        super(id, mealModel);

        setVisible(false);
        setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);

        var dataProvider = new MealWeekDayDataProvider(new MockMealDayList().getMealDayList());

        var form = new Form<Void>("form");
        form.add(new SimpleMealCalendarGridView("rows", dataProvider, mealModel));
        form.add(new CloseAjaxLink("close"));
        form.add(new SummaryLink("summary"));
        add(form);
    }

    private class CloseAjaxLink extends LoadingAjaxLink
    {
        public CloseAjaxLink(String id) { super(id); }

        @Override
        public IModel<?> getBody() { return new ResourceModel("CLOSE").wrapOnAssignment(this); }

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target)
        {
            if (target != null) {
                SimpleMealCalendarFormPopup.this.setVisible(false);
                target.add(this, SimpleMealCalendarFormPopup.this);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class SummaryLink extends Link<Void> {}
```

```html
SimpleMealCalendarFormPopup.html


<tr wicket:id="rows">
  <td>
    <span wicket:id="meal_time"></span>
  </td>
  <td wicket:id="cols">
    <label wicket:id="label">
      <input class="has-tooltip-warning" type="checkbox" wicket:id="mealSelected"/>
    </label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

```java
public class SimpleMealCalendarGridView extends GridView<MealWeekDay>
{
    private IModel<Meal> mealModel;

    public SimpleMealCalendarGridView(String id, IDataProvider<MealWeekDay> dataProvider, IModel<Meal> mealModel)
    {
        super(id, dataProvider);
        this.mealModel = mealModel;
    }

    @Override
    protected void populateEmptyItem(Item<MealWeekDay> item) {}

    @Override
    protected void populateItem(Item<MealWeekDay> item)
    {
        var label_container = new LabelContainer("label", item.getModel());
        label_container.add(new MealCheckBox("mealSelected", item.getModel()));
        item.add(label_container);
    }

    @Override
    protected Item<?> newRowItem(String id, int index)
    {
        return new FirstItemInGridRow(id, index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRows() { return 6; }

    @Override
    public int getColumns() { return 7; }

    @Override
    protected void onDetach()
    {
        super.onDetach();
        if (mealModel != null) { mealModel.detach(); }
    }

    private class LabelContainer extends WebMarkupContainer
    {
        public LabelContainer(String id, IModel<MealWeekDay> mealWeekDayModel)
        {
            super(id, mealWeekDayModel);
            add(new AttributeAppender("class", "has-background-warning")
            {
                @Override
                public boolean isEnabled(Component component)
                {
                    var meal_week_day = (MealWeekDay) getDefaultModelObject();
                    return meal_week_day.isMealSelected();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private class MealCheckBox extends CheckBox { // omitted }
}
```

```java
FirstItemInGridRow.java

public class FirstItemInGridRow extends Item<String>
{
    public FirstItemInGridRow(String id, int index)
    {
        super(id, index); // index = grid row number
        ResourceModel translation = switch (index)
            {
                case 0 -> new ResourceModel("mealTimes.BREAKFAST");
                case 1 -> new ResourceModel("mealTimes.LUNCH");
                case 2 -> new ResourceModel("mealTimes.DINNER_I");
                case 3 -> new ResourceModel("mealTimes.DINNER_II");
                case 4 -> new ResourceModel("mealTimes.ELEVENSES");
                case 5 -> new ResourceModel("mealTimes.SUPPER");
                default -> throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + index);
            };
        add(new Label("meal_time", translation));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GridView is used to display items of a IDataProvider in a grid; you break that by introducing an additional component "meal_time" in each row:

When GridView is trying to reuse already existing items, it stumbles over your additional component, which is not expected to be there, since it doesn't represent an element in your data.

IMHO it would be easier to just go with two nested repeaters (RefreshingView or ListView).

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataTable, it will be much easier. Your data provider should return a model for the table row. After that, your code will look something like this :

```
    var columns = new ArrayList<IColumn<Row,String>>();
    columns.add(new TitleColumn());
    DAYS.forEach(day -> columns.add(new DayColumn(day)));
    var dataProvider = new RowsDataProvider();
    var table = new DataTable<>("tableId", columns, dataProvider, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

In the `fillItem` method of the `DayColumn` class you can use the `AjaxCheckBox` for changing values in the row model.

Comment: svenmeier, a.alexander - thank you guys for your help